# Plotting curves given by equations in R

Tags: r, graphics

In R, is there a way to plot 2D curves given by equations? For example, how can I plot the hyperbola given by equation x^2 - 3*y^2 + 2*x*y - 20 = 0?

Comment: I do believe those will be hyperbolae (or whatever the proper plural of that word is).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `contour` to plot the two branches of your hyperbola.

```
f <- function(x,y) x^2 - 3*y^2 + 2*x*y - 20
x <- y <- seq(-10,10,length=100)
z <- outer(x,y,f)
contour(
  x=x, y=x, z=z, 
  levels=0, las=1, drawlabels=FALSE, lwd=3
)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorta surprised that there isn't a way to plot this directly.  `plot(fun=..., xlim=..., ylim=...)` or a way to feed x and y to `stat_function` in `ggplot2`.

Comment: Okay, I have no idea how that `outer` statement works. I could get a similar plot by solving for `x` or `y` first, but this is very efficient. Care to explain?

Comment: `outer(x,y,f)` returns the matrix `z[i,j]=f(x[i],y[j])`, 
i.e., it evaluates the function on a grid.
You can try `image(z)` or `contour(z)` to visualize `z`.
Solving for x or y numerically is problematic 
because, for a given value of x, 
there may be several corresponding values of y.
(Of course, it can easily be done formally 
with a Computer Algebra System: maxima, yacas, etc.)

Comment: `curve3d` from the `emdbook` package gives a slight shortcut: `emdbook::curve3d(x^2 - 3*y^2 + 2*x*y - 20, xlim=c(-10,10),ylim=c(-10,10),n=c(100,100),
+ sys3d="contour",levels=0)`

Comment: @Ben Bolker: Excellent suggestion; I'm actually taking a Differential Geometry course now and this function will be extremely helpful.  Also, when I started to learn R in 2008, I used Ecological Models and Data in R and found it to be very helpful.  Is there any way to rotate the plotted surface?

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record - a ggplot version

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
f <- function(x,y) x^2 - 3*y^2 + 2*x*y - 20
seq(-10,+10,length=100) %>%
    expand.grid(x=.,y=.) %>%
    mutate(z=f(x,y)) %>%
    ggplot +
    aes(x=x,y=y,z=z) +
    stat_contour(breaks=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe the solution can be transforming the equation into a formula and use curve() to make a plot.

`curve(sqrt(4/9*x^2-20/3) + x/3,-20,20)`